# Adding class to a field within a channel form

Tags: safecracker, channel, channel-fields

{label:skills}:
    
    {field:skills}

I am trying to add a class to the field skills. Cant find any documentation on adding a class to this field. Im sure its a simple fix, anyone got the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Via the Channel Entries form, you'll have to go by [the docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/), I thought you could add attributes however I was thinking of a freeform field(`{freeform:field:my field attr:class="testClass"}`, not a SAEF/Channel Entries field unfortunatly.

The examples show you how to make your form, with complete markup autonomously here : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/examples.html#entry-form-without-using-the-custom-fields-loop.

Assuming its a basic text field :

```
    <label for="my_field_name">{label:skills}</label>
    <input type="text" class="testClass" name="my_field_name" id="my_field_name" value="{skills}">
```

If you look through the examples, the label:field syntax can be useful for the complex types like grid or relationship (see here also : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#including-assets) but it sounds like you'd be better suited by leveraging your power HTML skillz.